# Box2d: Place object besides another one precisely?

Tags: box2d

I was wondering about how to place fixtures right beside another one. Btw. I have probably confused myself.
So here is what I want to do:
[LIKE THIS ILLUSTRATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOtZl.png)

Could I just accomplish this by applying the sum of something like this positionX of leftWall + sizeX/2 of leftWall + sizeX/2 of box, to the box climbing the wall? Or is there some box2d function that automatically calculates the position?
After I have accomplished this, I will add a constant velocity to the box and therefore I need it to be exact plus the fact that it looks better. I have just confused myself too much and I do not know how but can anybody tell me what they would do?
Thanks! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with "the sum of something".
I don't see it is a problem.
If you really dislike it, just write your own function to do it.
As you already know, it is not hard.

### Detail

Box2D is not an architectural library.
As far as I know, there is no such function.
In 3D Physics and Graphics, I also faced a little inconvenience like this.
There are 2 choices for me :-

- hard code "the sum of something"   (I start to love this phrase.)
- encapsulate such library (e.g. Box2D)    / code a utility function

I usually pick one of the choices, depends on situation.
Because it is only little inconvenience, I believe the first is suitable for your situation.

By the way, [there are reserved margin between colliding fixtures](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/fixtures), so I think you can't set the exact position.

> there is always a small margin of space added around the fixture by default.

Comment: Thanks man, that is really appreciated! However, you said this "Box2D is not an architectural library.
As far as I know, there is no such function.". So how come that this is a scenario: I have a static wall on the left side of the screen with the width of  4 and then I create a dynamic box with the purpose of placing it right beside the wall and when i simply type in a position for that dynamic box that is > the x position of the wall(with anchor point of 0.5) and < the x position of the wall + half its size | Then the dynamic box is somehow placing right beside the wall and not inside?

Comment: So it seems like that box2d is doing something smart in order to place the box right beside the wall correct?

Comment: @npp Without seeing your code, I will take a guess.   I think Box2D uses collision solver to shift it.   Roughly speaking, Physic Engines, usually tries to ensure that all objects not overlap each other.   If that is your case, beware that one should not rely on the auto-adjustment too much - it is not so predictable/reliable.

Comment: @npp To be sure, try to disable collision e.g. set `mask = 0` for both objects.   Then, do many experiment.  Each test case, set different `x` (that you set) to the dynamic box, and observe the result.  If I am correct, in every case, it will not "snap" anymore.  (I would be very surprised if it still snaps in some cases.)

Comment: But I do want the snap I think since that it automatically places the player right beside the wall but can you tell me why it happens?

Comment: @npp see the third comment. "Without seeing your code ...".  If you really want the snap, I think write a game-engine with GUI is an answer. (usually cost a lot, i.e. 1.5+ year, not worth just for this problem)

Answer (score 1):

**An explanation of what's going on...**

For static and kinematic bodies, where you place them is where they'll be. In other words, if you call `b2Body::SetTransform` with a position of `pos` and then call `b2Body::GetPosition`, the returned value should equal `pos`. This should hold true even if these bodies overlap each other. They won't move unless you tell them to.

Dynamic bodies behave differently however. They behave more like we'd expect solid bodies to behave in the real world. But we can do things to them still that couldn't practically be done to real solid objects. For instance, we can call `b2Body::SetTransform` on one dynamic body to place it (or part of it) within another body. Now the physics engine works to figure out where to move the dynamic body so that it's not within the other body anymore (and in a way that's intended to appear reasonable enough given what the initial overlap may look like).

More precisely, the 2.3.2 Box2D library will resolve the overlap of two bodies (where one or both are dynamic) as much as `b2_maxLinearCorrection` for each position iteration until `minSeparation >= -3.0f * b2_linearSlop` where `minSeparation` is the distance separating the closest vertices (of both shapes) in the separating plane minus the sum of the vertex radiuses (of both shapes). The "sequential solver" does this via impulses but without influencing the body velocity values so that neither body acts as if it had any additional momentum.

You can take a look at the code involved in the `b2ContactSolver::SolvePositionConstraints` method of the [`b2ContactSolver.cpp`](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/master/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/Contacts/b2ContactSolver.cpp) file.

So in a sense, the Box2D world step "calculates the position" for you. Note however the following caveats:

1. This position resolution doesn't always complete in one step. I.e. users may watch as the box moves out from the wall till it appears entirely out.
2. If you place the box too far into the wall, it will appear on the opposite side of the wall.
3. You may want to factor in to your expectations the total of the vertex radiuses - i.e. sum the values of the shapes' `m_radius` values. This is referred to as the reserved margin of space. For two polygons, this will be `4.0f * b2_linearSlop` or `0.02f` (2 centimeters).

**Insofar as placing an object beside another precisely then:**

- You can place non-dynamic bodies beside each other as precisely as floating-point values allow.
- You can place a dynamic body beside another body only as close as position resolution allows (and only as precisely as floating-point values allow). Any closer, and the "sequential solver" will move it back out.

Comment: @npp Given your comment, please consider up-voting my answer. Thanks!